# what exactly is the use of the gstreamer filter in Kurento Media Server

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, kurento

According to Kurento documentation: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_API.html

**GstreamerFilter is a generic filter interface that allow use GStreamer filter in Kurento Media Pipelines.**

I was trying to find **Gstreamer filters** on google, all I found was **Gstreamer plugins**. (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/

Does this mean I can use the Kurento Gstreamer filter, to add plugins such as rtph264depay and rtmpsink with it?

e.g.

```
WebRTC endpoint > RTP Endpoint > (rtph264depay) Gstreamer filter  (rtmpsink) > RTMP server.
```

**All without installing Gstreamer separately?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GstreamerFilter allows you to configure a filter using a native GStreamer filter (the same way than when you are using `gst-launch-1.0`). For example, the following Kurento filter allows to rotate horizontally your media within KMS:

```
GStreamerFilter filter = new GStreamerFilter.Builder(pipeline, "videoflip method=horizontal-flip").build();
```

Said that, and regarding your question, for the best of my knowledge, I think so, you can use GstreamerFilter to use rtph264depay and rtmpsink.

Comment: Hello Boni, is there any documentation of all these functionality provided by GStreamFilter ? As I am working on trying to find out number of faces.

Comment: In fact there is not much documentation about it, sorry. For the best of my knowledge, currently there is only available the [JavaDoc](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/javadoc/index.html) and [JsDoc](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/jsdoc/kurento-client-js/node_modules_kurento-client-filters_lib_GStreamerFilter.js.html) of the of GStreamerFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Boni Garcia 's code is right.

But if you replace "videoflip method=horizontal-flip" as "rtmpsink location=rtmp://deque.me/live/test01", you will get a error message: "Given command is not valid, pad templates does not match".

You can go deeper to check kms-filter source code from https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters, in kms-filters/src/server/implementation/objects/GStreamerFilterImpl.cpp there is a line:

```
     99     throw KurentoException (MARSHALL_ERROR,
     100                             "Given command is not valid, pad templates does not match");
```

I afraid you can't use GstreamerFilter to send data to rtmp server, maybe you should modify the source code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

## Kurento

Just looking at the [source](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/blob/master/src/server/implementation/objects/GStreamerFilterImpl.cpp#L36) - the `GStreamerFilter` is limited to simple GStreamer plugins.  They reject bins and I don't see how you would specify/isolate multiple pads so it probably won't do it.

(EDIT: Maybe I'm wrong here - I'm still learning.  I see the mixer [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/kN97ow37piU) isolating media types and that makes me think it may be possible)

## gstreamer

On the other hand installing gstreamer shouldn't really be that much overhead - then link the output RTP connection to a `gst-launch` pipeline that can output RTMP.  It just sucks you can't manage the full pipeline using kurento.

(I don't know what that pipeline would look like - investigating it myself.  It's something like this:

`gst-launch-1.5 -v   \
udpsrc port=9999  caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! mux.   \
multifilesrc location=sample.aac loop=1 ! aacparse ! mux.  \
mpegtsmux name=mux  mux. ! rtpmp2tpay ! queue ! udpsink host=10.20.20.20 port=5000`

But I'm faking audio in this and haven't gotten the full stream working)

## back to kurento

Further exploration suggested maybe the [Composite](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.6.1/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/Composite.html) `MediaElement` would work (tl;dr: no):

```
Composite composite = new Composite.Builder(pipeline).build();
HubPort in_audio = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
HubPort in_video = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
HubPort out_composite = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();

GStreamerFilter filter = new GStreamerFilter.Builder(pipeline, "rtmpsink location=rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/live_stream_720p").build();

webRtcEndpoint.connect(in_audio, MediaType.AUDIO);
webRtcEndpoint.connect(in_video, MediaType.VIDEO);

out_composite.connect(filter);
```

results in (kurento logs):

```
...15,011560 21495 [0x4f01700]   debug KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:422 processMessage()  Message: >{"id":28,"method":"create","params":{"type":"GStreamerFilter","constructorParams":{"mediaPipeline":"5751ec53_kurento.MediaPipeline","command":"rtmpsink location=rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/live_stream_720p"},"properties":{},"sessionId":"d8abb1d8"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}<
...15,011862 21495 [0x4f01700]   debug KurentoGStreamerFilterImpl GStreamerFilterImpl.cpp:47 GStreamerFilterImpl()  Command rtmpsink location=rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/live_stream_720p
...15,015698 21495 [0x4f01700]   error filterelement             kmsfilterelement.c:148 kms_filter_element_set_filter() <kmsfilterelement0>  Invalid factory "rtmpsink", unexpected pad templates
...15,016841 21495 [0x4f01700]   debug KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:424 processMessage()  Response: >{"error":{"code":40001,"data":{"type":"MARSHALL_ERROR"},"message":"Given command is not valid, pad templates does not match"},"id":28,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I.e. failure.